# How to add less/more command like pagination in a custom CLI?

Tags: node.js, linux, command-line-interface, oclif

##### I'm building a CLI with Node.js and want to add less/more like pagination.

[image: screenshot]

I can just `stdout` the output and pipe it to `less` like this

[image]

but I'm not able to add the text highlight just like `git log` in the first picture.

I have searched about it but couldn't find any relevant info. Would really appreciate any help or references

Comment: Just use `<your command> | less -R`

Comment: @tink Yes I can pipe the output to less but I want some part of the output to be highlighted just like git log (also mentioned in the question)

Comment: Have you actually  **tried** it with the `-R`?  `less` doesn't strip control characters with `-R` and things retain colour.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with `-R` flag. Could it be because I'm using a third-party package to highlight the output? 
It's a CLI built with Node.js and I'm using `chalk` to add color to the console.
https://github.com/abhagsain/ai-cli

Comment: Excellent question ... maybe that framework skips control characters when it writes to a pipe. If you e.g. try colourised `ls` output into `less -R` - does that work for you? Because on my Ubuntu install it sure does.

Comment: No, `ls | less -R` not working highlighting text for me either  I'm on Mac btw using the built-in terminal and also VSCode's integrated terminal

Comment: That's weird ... when I try on the mac (Monterey, 12.6.1) I keep coloured output in `less` in both `terminal.app` and `iTerm2` (the letter being my preference). Does `ls` give colour for you normally? If not, try `ls -l --color=always| less -R` ...

Comment: Yes, it shows color normally.
I'm getting this error `ls: illegal option -- =` also I forgot to mention that I'm using `ohmyzsh` with power10k theme. 

I'll go through github's CLI source code to understand how they are doing it with `gh search prs query` https://github.com/cli/cli
I don't know golang but let's see. Thank you so much for your time.